# Can't access MySQL database created using a docker image

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm trying to run [wackopicko](https://github.com/adamdoupe/WackoPicko) on my MacBook Air using the provided [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/adamdoupe/wackopicko/). When I run the command:

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:8080:80 -it adamdoupe/wackopicko
```

I get the following output: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwKQw.png)

I'm able to access the application on localhost, create a new user and login with that user. My issue is with accessing the database on my terminal to see the user information. According to the output, MySQL has been installed and a root and admin have been created. However, I don't have MySQL installed on my laptop. If I run the command:

```
mysql -uroot
```

I get the following output:

```
mysql: command not found
```

I have tried installing mysql and I logged in as root, however, I didn't see the wackopicko database and users that were supposed to be created when I run the docker file. I'm not familiar with docker, but I tried looking online to find a solution and haven't found one yet. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mysql installed inside the docker container, to run what you want, first you have to know the container id:

```
docker ps
```

Then go inside container with:

```
docker exec -it yourcontainerid /bin/bash
```

Once inside the container

```
mysql -uroot
```